# How to add GIF image to progress bar and the percentage ratio just like a voting poll?

Tags: android, animation, gif, progress

I am working on progress bar loading with GIF image or simply animation XML in android. How can I add a GIF file to progress bar  in android . And how to show the percentage ratio just like a voting poll in progress bar e.g.50%?

Can anyone suggest me the right way to achieve it.

Comment: You can share the sample image to show the type of progress bar you want more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to add layout to place both of them. Also you have to do alignment to place progressbar above ImageView. If you are adding ImageView dynamically, add progress bar also dynamically.

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/your_image" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by following code :

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rell"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp" >

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
                style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
                android:layout_width="135dp"
                android:layout_height="91dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp" />


      <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:background="@drawable/loading_img" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to display a gif, see this post:

http://weavora.com/blog/2012/02/07/android-and-how-to-use-animated-gifs/